# Loop features using x/y coordinates

Tags: python, gis

Hey all I'm having trouble with this task, Loop each feature in NA_Cities.shp, use cursors to read x/y coordinates of each city point;

```
import arcpy
import math

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

folderpath = r'C:\Users\Michaelf\Desktop\GEOG M173\LabData'

In_Lakes = folderpath + '\NA_Big_Lakes.shp'
In_Cities = folderpath + '\NA_Cities.shp'
Out_Lakes = folderpath + '\New_Lakes.shp'

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management (In_Lakes, Out_Lakes)

fields = [
    ('City', 'TEXT'),
    ('Admin', 'TEXT'),
    ('Country_', 'TEXT'),
    ('Population', 'LONG'),
]

for field in fields:
    arcpy.AddField_management(*(Out_Lakes,) + field)

city_name_list = []
city_admin_list = []
city_country_list = []
city_pop_list = []

city_cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(In_Cities)

for city in city_cursor:
    city_name_list.append(city.CITY_NAME)
    city_admin_list.append(city.ADMIN_NAME)
    city_country_list.append(city.CNTRY_NAME)
    city_pop_list.append(city.POPULATION)

lakes_cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(Out_Lakes)

city_length = len(city_X_list)

for lake in lakes_cursor:
    distance_to_shore = []
    for city in range(0, city_length - 1):
       distance_to_shore = arcpy.Near_analysis(import_cities_feature, import_lake_feature)
       distance_shore.append(distance_to_shore)

closest_city = min(distance_cntrd_list)
closest_city_index = distance_cntrd_list.index(closest_city)

lake.city = city_name_list[closest_city_index]
lake.Admin = city_admin_list [closest_city_index]
lake.Population = city_pop_list [closest_city_index]
lake.Country_ = city_country_list [closest_city_index]
lakes_cursor.updateRow(lake)


del city_cursor, lakes_cursor, city, lake
```

Here is an updated version of my complete code,
Thanks in advance for any feedback or advice!

Answer (score 0):

Don't be scared to run your code. It is the best way of debugging and optimizing. And for your question: It is useful to store the x and y values. A useful format would be a dict like this: {city_name:(x, y, more_data)}

Comment: Thanks, I ran the code and I get an error that the `name city length isn't defined`

Comment: It doesn't work now, I could use some help with that if possible?

Comment: Of course. Could you update the code with what you have now and what doesn't work and what you want? Then i will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined city_X_list? And on which line did you get the error?
Also deleting data from memoy isn't necessary because python does this automatically when it exits a function or script. Only when you use big data sets and it needs to be removed from ram halfway in a function you need to use del.

Comment: I had defined city_X_list previously but I don't think so know. I am trying to here is what I'm trying to do

Comment: You may refer to the following logic to structure your Python script: àStep 1: copy NA_Big_Lakes.shp to a new lake shapefile, add in empty fields for city information; àStep 2: Loop each feature in NA_Cities.shp, use cursors to read x/y coordinates of each city point;  àStep 3: Loop each feature in the new lake shapefile, use geometry cursors to read vertex coordinates of this lake polygon, identify the city that is the closest to the lake’s vertex, and add the city information into the fields of this lake feature.

Comment: I suppose it works when you have fixed the city_X_list, or not?

Comment: It does work with a fixed city_X_list I am struggling with step 3 I believe I'm not sure how to

Comment: I'm not good at that kind of math, so I can't help you with that. Sorry and good luck!